# Length of the longest substring without repeating characters

Tags: python

I wrote this code in Python to solve the problem of **Length of the longest substring without repeating characters**. It works with small strings but not with larger strings.

```py
def lengthOfLongestSubstring(s):
    ns = []
    ns[:0] = s
    seq = ''
    result = 0
    for i in ns:
        if not(i in seq):
            seq += i
        else:
            if len(seq) > result:
                result = len(seq)
            seq = ''
   return result
```

```py
>>> lengthOfLongestSubstring('abrkaabcdefghijjxxx')
10
>>> lengthOfLongestSubstring('qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqaaaaaaaaaaaaasssssssssssssssssssssssssssssqdjfdshauhhdsihqdsdqgsjdgsqgsqdgusqdgyudgyqgdysugdyqgdyqsgdsydgqygsqydsqgydgsqdysgyqgdyqdgsydgsydgqysgdsqydgsqyudgysqgdsqygdsqydgqdugqysqgdyqsudgqygazertyuiopqsdfghjklm')
6
>>>
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to include some examples of strings for which you get the incorrect result, and the exact result you get in those cases?

Comment: Is this case-sensitive or case-insensitive? I.e. Is the longest substring of _abcABC_ **abc** or **abcABC**?

Comment: It's not the length, it's that you start over completely when a character is repeated. For instance, if the input is "abcad", you will find "abc", but then "reset" when you find the second "a", so you will never find "bcad". (Use small and systematic test cases, not large and arbitrary ones.)

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks, I'll try to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

One bug I found was that if the string ends with the longest substring, then it's not counted because it never enters the if check because the for loop ends.
Another bug I found was that when you've reached a repeating character, the new "seq" variable shouldn't be empty, it should just ignore the character that was repeated. (So start from that character's index + 1)

The following code solves both the bugs

```
class Solution:
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s):
        ns=[]
        ns[:0]=s
        seq=''
        result=0
        for i in ns:
            if not(i in seq):
               seq+=i
            else:
               if len(seq) > result:
                   result=len(seq)
                #New substring starts with the character after the  repeating character and all that follow
                seq=seq[seq.index(i)+1:]

        # Here we are testing the last substring
        if len(seq) > result:
            result=len(seq)
        return result    

print(Solution().lengthOfLongestSubstring('qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqaaaaaaaaaaaaasssssssssssssssssssssssssssssqdjfdshauhhdsihqdsdqgsjdgsqgsqdgusqdgyudgyqgdysugdyqgdyqsgdsydgqygsqydsqgydgsqdysgyqgdyqdgsydgsydgqysgdsqydgsqyudgysqgdsqygdsqydgqdugqysqgdyqsudgqygazertyuiopqsdfghjklm'))
```

Gives you "19" for "azertuiopqsdfghjklm"

Answer (score 0):

**final solution**

```
    class Solution:
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s):
      result=0
      visited=[0]*128
      s = s.upper()
      n=len(s)
      for i in range(n) :
        for j in  range(i,n) :
            if visited[ord(s[j])]==0 :
                visited[ord(s[j])]=1
            else:
                break
        visited=[0]*128
        if (result<j-i+1):
           result=j-i+1
        if j==n-1:
            break
      return result  

print("RES="+str(Solution().lengthOfLongestSubstring('')))
```